# Reversing the changes on CSS caused by the animation effect using jquery.animate() and jquery.scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Is there a way to reverse the CSS changes caused by `jQuery.animate()` according to the position of the scroll ? I am working on a website where I want a certain animation effect to occur on an element when a user scrolls down. After that when the user scrolls up the element must get back to its previous state. an example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(this.scrollTop() >= 300){  //Scrolling down to a point 300 or more
        $('.foo').animate({
            'width': 100 
           'height': 100 
        }, 500, 'swing');     
     }
});
```

As you can see from the above snippet, the effect happens when the user scrolls down. Now below is a code which I can logically think of as to how the reverse effect will work:

```
if(this.scrollTop() <= 300) {  //Scrolling down to a point 300 or more    
    $('.foo').animate({
        'width': 10 
        'height': 10
    }, 500, 'swing');     
 }
```

Click [**THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/o247v1k2/) to see the code in action and get a better insight.

I have seen a lot of plugins doing this however, Is there a better way of doing the above mentioned scenario using just `jQuery.animate()` binded by the `jQuery.scroll()` ? If so, Could you please show me an example ? or could you direct me to a link ? Please guide me/advice me.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Throw `stop()` in there and do some debouncing. You are queuing up significant numbers of animations due to scroll event fires many times a second. Also no need to call the animation if it is already done for that stage

Comment: @charlietfl hmm... Could you please give me an example illustrating your explanation ? would be really grateful of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class for that, create a class with the properties you want, in your case

```
.scrolled {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Then addClass, it accepts the other options you wanted, so you can

```
if(this.scrollTop() >= 300){
    this.addClass('scrolled', 500, 'swing');
}

if(this.scrollTop() < 300){
    this.removeClass('scrolled', 500, 'swing);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... then what if I have more than 5 elements I want to have a 5 different effects on at the same time ? Will the addClass/removeClass be effective then ?

Comment: I see no other way, the only thing I would do would be to have meaningful class names (instead of scrolled) and wrap all the transformations into a function, to aggregate the behaviour

Comment: You should accept an answer if you think it answers the question in a good way

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to force jquery to edit the CSS of the object, you could tell it to add/remove classes instead which will give you a similar effect.

If your object's style is already composed as 10px width/height, then you can have a style like

```
.bar{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

and in your javascript code:

```
if(this.scrollTop() >= 300){
    this.addClass('bar');
}
```

then you can just do

```
removeClass('bar');
```

when you don't need it.

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: will this be effective if have a lot elements I want to have an animation effect on ? what about the easing ?